# Forge API: Get all changed items

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I need to get a list of all changed items in my  project in BIM 360. Can I do this using forge-api.

Comment: Could you clarify which kind of change you want to monitor? Forge Webhook API supports various events such as document version added,  updated, folder modified, folder deleted etc. This is a complete list: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/

Comment: I think something like [this project by Augusto](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360notifier) could help you out. If you have a forge related issue its always a good idea to look trough the repos in github. cheers

Comment: If my service is not available and I will miss some webhook events, how can I get all the changes that were made after the last webhook event received

Answer (score 0):

Ho, regarding with the latest question [If my service is not available and I will miss some webhook events, how can I get all the changes that were made after the last webhook event received] :

If your requirement is to know which items are changed in one folder of Docs, Search API with filter can be of use. e.g. the endpoint below will return all items which are updated since a certain time.

```
 https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{{project_id_with_b}}/folders/{{one_folder_id}}/search?filter[attributes.lastModifiedTime]-ge=2019-10-15
```

More filters options are described at
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/

While if you wanted to know all updates in one call, I do not see currently the way is available. While, Activity API is on the way, it might be helpful to know all activities during a certain dates, then you could filter out what you are interested in and locate the corresponding module>>files/resources etc.. but Activities may probably be categorized with specific scopes e.g. admin activities, project actives, issue activities etc. so it is not one call knows all updates.. And these APIs may not be exposed in the same time.